# split string by spaces properly accounting for quotes and backslashes (ruby)

Tags: ruby, regex

I want to split a string (insecure foreign line, like exim_mainlog line) by spaces, but not by  spaces that are inside of double quotes, and ignore if the quote is escaped by a backslash like `\"`, and ignore the backslash if it is just escaped like `\\`. Without slow parsing the string manually with FSM.

**Example line**:

`U=mailnull T="test \"quote\" and wild blackslash\\" P=esmtps`

**Should be split into**:

`["U=mailnull", "T=\"test \\\"quote\\\" and wild blackslash\\\"", "P=esmtps"]`

(Btw, I think ruby should had method for such split.., sigh).

Answer (score 8):

I think I found simple enough solution: `input.scan(/(?:"(?:\\.|[^"])*"|[^" ])+/)`

Comment: Hi Catpnosis. Can you please explain this?

Comment: @vijikumar scan() will collect matched words, it will match any continuity (latest `+`) of non-quote/space characters (`[^" ]`), or if quote begin (`"(`) it will match until closing quote (`)*"`) any (`*`) escaped chars (`\\.`) or non-quote chars (`[^"]`).